# Contour integral and primitive

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Given

$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{i(1-y)-x}$$

I have to integrate $f$ over the origin-centered circle of radius 4. I see that

$$f(x,y)=-\frac{2x+i2(1-y)}{x^2+(1-y)^2}$$

There is a singularity in $-i$ so I use the residues theorem. I also know I can integrate over any other closed curve which contains the singularity and obtaining the same result.

Is it the same if I integrate the function:

$$g(z)=-\frac{2z}{|z|^2}$$

over the unit circle?

How can i find the residues?

What does it mean to find the primitive of a complex function?

Please, suggest some resource to study this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Your function $f$ agrees with $f(z)=2/(i-z)$. If you know of [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula) you can apply it immediately to the function $z\mapsto -2$ and with point $a=i$.

Comment: I understand now, both with the integral formula and the residue. Can I say the antiderivative is $-2\ln(i-z)$?

Comment: No, it seems I can't. I have to study the two differential forms associated to f(z) or something like that, right?
IF f(z) is holomorphic in a simply connected domain then the two forms are exact and have primitive. From these I can find the primitive of f(z).
In this case I can remove an half line to make the domain simply connected. Now, can I integrate the function with the usual rules?
What can I say if I want to consider the entire domain? Do I have to prove that the forms are not exact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting $z=(x,0)$, we get that $$f\left ( x,0 \right )=\frac{2}{i-z}=f\left ( z \right )$$

We see that the function has a pole at $z=i$, thus $$\oint_{\left | z=4 \right |} f\left ( z \right )dz=2 \pi i Res_{z=i} f\left ( z \right )$$
Knowing that we can use the following formula to calculate the residue at a first order pole : $$Res_{z=z_k}\frac{f\left ( z \right )}{g\left ( z \right )}=\lim _{z\rightarrow z_k}\frac{f\left ( z \right )}{g^{'}\left ( z \right )}$$
It is now clear that 
$$\oint_{\left | z=4 \right |} f\left ( z \right )dz=-4 \pi i$$
Note that you can calculate the antiderivative(in the usual, real sense) only when a function has no poles(or other singularities) in $\mathbb{C}$, which is really not the case here, meaning that the integral IS dependent on the path of integration( think of non-conservative fields),